# cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown in gitlab Kubernetes executor

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab

```html
 image: docker:19.03.13
variables:
  GIT_DEPTH: "0"
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2376  
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "$DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR/client"
```

I am running my runner on  Kubernetes executor added docker dind in yaml file. when docker build command run it shows "cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown".

Comment: I just fixed this by bumping my docker image version to docker:20.10.16
Seems there's issues with running docker 19.03 on CRI/O (kubernetes container runtime). I know this is not helpful if you had other reasons you were holding back to the older version.